# Why is turning on Event Scheduler Maxing my CPU?

Tags: mysql, optimization, configuration, cpu, mysql-event

I have search the web for the last week trying to figure this out.
I have exported my tables and events, re-installed the lastest MySQL and imported.
I have tried checking individual procedures.

My situation has me at a complete standstill, here it is:
I install the latest MySQL 8.0 from MySQL Installer on Windows 10 x64-bit, here is the slightly modified my.ini file: [my.ini](https://pastebin.com/md9VbSEn)

Whenever I enable event_scheduler (with any form of an activated event, even a single one liner "SELECT * FROM [Table_Without_Data];") which reoccurs every second,
I see an indefinite number of "event_worker" threads opening *all* of which are stuck in the "opening tables" state and sleeping.
My CPU maxes out, and slows down my whole pc.

Additionally I have 8Gb RAM and an i7-3520M CPU @ 2.90GHz

It does not appear when I check full processlist that anything is frozen because of locks which only leaves me to believe it is something in the server configuration.

I also notice that this will not occur if i start the DB and edit the scheduled event, then set event_scheduler=ON, until I send a query anyhow.

Any ideas? Need any further info?

---

***UPDATE***

---

After extenuating efforts to try to crowd source a solution, I've decided this must be a MySQL bug and I've shared it here: [BUG#: 100449](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=100449) Other reference post is here: [Stack Overflow - DDeathlonger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63223519/why-is-mysql-event-scheduler-stuck-opening-tables)

Comment: Have you tried running mysqladmin debug? Please see here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/events-status-info.html

Comment: Check various dates.  It smells like the Event Scheduler is running lots of events that it missed since whenever.

Comment: Seeing as I got no answers the first time, I made a new post on stack overflow, same issue, no answers. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63223519/why-is-mysql-event-scheduler-stuck-opening-tables

Comment: Please post complete TEXT results of SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;  Thanks

Comment: @DDeathlonger Please review these restrictions, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-program-restrictions.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer actually has turned out to be a bug which is reproducible - [Bug#: 100449](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=100449)